# MobileSafari (iOS Safari): Is there a way to prevent horizontal/vertical scroll "snapping"?

Tags: ios, css, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I've got a web app which displays a scrollable view of a 2D diagram, and I am trying to allow the user to more easily let the view always follow the finger.

The default behavior is such that most swiping motions result in either a vertical or horizontally constrained movement, which is helpful for reading text but not so much for my use case.

Writing custom touch event code to directly set scroll is one possibility but that makes it difficult to bring back scroll momentum. In addition, the native functionality is capable of doing some special things behind the scenes, like suspend JS operations and avoid re-renders, which helps overall performance.

Is there a CSS style that can control the directional control behavior?

Comment: Pls clearify, you want momentum or not?

Comment: I do want momentum. I don't want directional constraint.

Comment: Does you page only contain diagram? O

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to specify the behaviour, but I've found that when I place my finger down without moving it then start moving it after a second it will allow me to scroll in all directions.

Maybe look into if [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) or something similar will work for you, since it includes momentum and you can explicitly specify whether you want to lock the direction or not.

Comment: I have heard from more than one person that something about holding your finger longer triggers it, but whenever I test this it is not the case. It appears to me that *only* the direction of initial movement is considered. I can hold it till *just* before the select feature pops up and then move straight down and then it is vertically constrained for the remainder of the touch. My suspicion is that users are somehow more apt to do a diagonal drag following their slightly longer hold.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right. I just tested more carefully and it seems like I can scroll in all directions as long as my swipe isn't within a certain degree of the horizontal or vertical axis, no matter how long or short my initial touch is.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the diagram overflow the page size:

```
#diagram{
    width: 2000px;
}
```

All other parts should be fixed:

```
#menu, etc{
    position: fixed
}
```

This way you can use the scroll of the page itself, that has no directional constraint.

To prevent the iPad to resize the content to fit device width you add this in `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=2000px">
```

Comment: This answer does not address the issue: It constrains it unless you **carefully** move your finger diagonally initially.

Comment: The "scroll of the page itself" has the directional constraints by default.